# How to prevent dynamically appended div from overflowing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to dynamically append a bunch of div elements containing words to my page (each has the .magnet class). However, many of them end up spilling outside the boundaries of the container, and I cannot figure out how to stop that from happening. If anyone could take a look at my jsfiddle and help me out, I would be very appreciative. I've also included my css code for the container below.
[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mszvbfoe/)

```
body {
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
background-color: #446b81;
}

.magnet {
width:45px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding:5px 25px;
font-family: Times;
font-size: 16px;
border:1px outset;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: It's becuase the position values being applied don't take into account the size of the element. You need to adjust for that.

Comment: I'm confused, wouldn't it automatically take into account the size of the parent div if it is being appended inside of it?

Comment: The size of the element being appended is what I was referring to. Remember that the positioning refers to the top left corner of the appended element. So you need to reduce the  maximum 'left' value by the width of the appended div. Ditto the top value and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you reduce the document width and height by some values? (50 and 100 are just random numbers but you can fix them with the exact size of the divs).

```
   testsub.css("top",Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(document).height()-50)));
   testsub.css("left",Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(document).width()-100)));
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mszvbfoe/5/

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work. However I realized my actual problem has to do with making the divs draggable via jquery UI. Wouldn't happen to have any insight as to why that is would you?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Put overflow:hidden; inside your container and fix the width for your container

```
#container 
{
    background-color: #446b81;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
}
```